# MySQL query needs to be more efficient

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO payments (invoice_id)
SELECT id
FROM   invoice
WHERE  NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT invoice_id
   FROM   payments
   WHERE  payments.invoice_id = invoice.id)
```

This is taking about 35 seconds.  There are times in production that a payment entry isn't created at the time an invoice is created.  I need to manually create payment rows with only the invoice_id of invoices which no payment records exist.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does `explain SELECT id FROM invoice WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT invoice_id FROM payments WHERE payments.invoice_id = invoice.id` shows ?

Comment: It just returns the number of rows affected.  If there are no payment records to add, it returns 0 rows affected.  I just ran it before posting here and it took 35 seconds and returned 8 rows affected.

Answer (score 0):

How big (rows) are your invoice and payments tables?
You might can use partition on any of these table or optimize them other way. 
Also I would recommend you to look through query plan (in your IDE) and check what costs a lot.

Comment: There are roughly 9900 invoices and 11575 payments.  We're not talking about large tables.  I'm just wondering if there isn't a more efficient way to query this.

Comment: I think you can add unique restriction on invoice_id field in payment table. So you don't need second query(in where statment).

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, that wouldn't work.  There can be multiple payments for each invoice.

Answer (score 0):

My bet is that it's taking a long time because of the correlated subquery (in the `EXISTS` predicate) is being run for *every* row in the `invoice` table, and I suspect that an appropriate index isn't available.

But before we jump on the knee jerk "add an index" bandwagon...

First, run an `EXPLAIN` on the `SELECT`. `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and grab the output from that; that will show the execution plan for the query.

(We're strongly suspicious that it's the `SELECT` that is slow, and that's it's not really the actual `INSERT` with performance bogged down by horrendous INSERT triggers and such.)

I suggest re-writing the query to use an **anti-join** pattern. (This isn't a panacea, but sometimes we can get *much* better performance, and that mostly depends on having suitable indexes available.)

```
 SELECT i.id
   FROM invoice i
   LEFT
   JOIN payments p
     ON p.invoice_id = i.id
  WHERE p.invoice_id IS NULL
```

That's going to return all rows from `invoice`, along with any matching rows from `payments`. The `LEFT` keyword makes that an outer join; that means that the query will also return rows from `invoice` that don't have a matching row in `payments`.

The "trick" is the predicate in the WHERE clause. By specifying that we only return rows where the `invoice_id` from `payments` is NULL, we filter out all `invoice` that had a matching row in `payments`.

We can run an `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` with that query. At a minimum, we're expecting to see the query making effective use of an index with leading column of `invoice_id`, and "Using index" in the Extra column.

If memory serves me, I think this can't be directly used in an `INSERT INTO payments`, because the query references the same table. The workaround is to reference this query as an inline view...

```
SELECT s.id
  FROM ( SELECT i.id
           FROM invoice i
           LEFT
           JOIN payments p
             ON p.invoice_id = i.id
          WHERE p.invoice_id IS NULL
       ) s
```

That does add some overhead, materializing the derived table. But it shouldn't be too bad for a relatively small set.

That query can serve as a rowsource for an `INSERT INTO payments (invoice_id)`

Without seeing the EXPLAIN output and the table definitions (including indexes), we're really just guessing what MySQL is doing.  We really want to see how the SELECT performs, the INSERT can't run any faster than the SELECT does.